# What step of the cloning process requires an egg cell? Have alternatives been attempted?

Tags: cell-biology, biotechnology, cloning

In the famous Dolly the sheep an egg cell was required. Why was specifically an egg cell required compared to say sperm cells or any other cell types?

Given that egg cells are not trivially harvested and culturable, have clones from alternatives been attempted?

Comment: This question doesn't show a lot of effort or nuance, but I am a bit puzzled why someone voted to close it for not being clear without providing some sort of comment.

Comment: I think this question deserves a chance and could yield some interesting answers. I've edited it to clear up any uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

egg cells are not required for cloning, plants for instance can be cloned just fine without them. Oocytes are commonly used in animals becasue they already contain some of the chemical markers and enzymes to begin development in the mother's body and keep her immune system from attacking it. In more derived animals development is not solely controlled by the the embryo but also by the mother, so using an egg cell helps trigger those processes of the mother. If you used a standard stem cell likely the mother immune system would just destroy it as a foreign entity.

Comment: "some of the chemical markers and enzymes to begin development" is almost an understatement.While it is almost possible to make specific cell types out of stem cells, the processes needed for embryo development are even more complex than that and as of today noone would be able to make a stem cell into an viable egg cell or embryo

Comment: Actually they have in mice, http://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/47256/title/From-Stem-Cell-to-Oocyte-In-a-Dish/

Comment: oh wow, I didn't know that (was already possible). Thanks for the link.